# How do I test database migrations?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, migration, migratordotnet

I'm using [Migrator.NET](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) to write database migrations for the application. Marc-André Cournoyer wrote:

> Like any code in your application you
>   *must* test your migrations. Ups and downs code. Do it part of your
>   continuous build process and test it
>   on as many different databases and
>   environment as you can.

How do I do that? Say I have the Up() method which creates a table and the Down() method which drops the same table and I'm using SQL Server. How would a test look like? Should I be running SQL query against the system tables, like `select * from sys.columns`, to check if the table was created and that it has the proper structure? What if we're using NHibernate?

**EDIT**
I mean migrations in the Rails ActiveRecord Migrations sense (creating, modifying and tearing down databases in small steps based on C# code).

**EDIT 2**
And [here](http://macournoyer.wordpress.com/2007/02/11/agile-database-fun-with-the-migrator/)'s where I read about that we should test migrations. The blog post is actually linked from Migrator's wiki.

Comment: I had the same question and have not found an answer yet. +1

Comment: I think this question is ambiguous, it could be written in a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you test your DAL - some sort of integration test?

You need more than a migration script, you also need a baseline script.  When you want to test a database upgrade, you should run all the scripts from the baseline on a testing/staging server to create the newest version of the database.  Then test your DAL against the up-to-date test database.  If all the DAL tests succeed then your migration should have been successful (otherwise your DAL tests are not complete enough).

It's an expensive test to run, but it's pretty much rock solid.  I'll personally admit to doing a lot of this manually at the moment; we have an in-house migration tool that will apply all scripts (including the baseline), so the test database setup and DAL tests are separate steps.  It works though.  If you want to make sure that a table was created, there's no better method than to actually try to insert data into it!

You can try to verify the results by looking at system catalogs and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views and so on, but ultimately the only way to be sure it's actually *working* is to try to *use* the new objects.  Just because the objects are there doesn't mean that they're functional.

Comment: Thanks. That's sort of how we ended doing it. We have the tests in two separate assemblies now - one for normal tests, the other for integration tests. The first batch runs before migrations and just tests the app logic and stuff, as well as the migrations, then the migrations are run and then the integration tests. This ensures that we have always use the current (latest) schema and that all database objects have been created. The integration tests use the NH model classes and just perform some CRUD operations.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this scrip can help you :

http://www.benzzon.se/forum/uploads/benzzon/2006-03-27_134824_sp_CompareDB.txt

this script compare two db.(structure and data)

Comment: No, that's not the kind of migrations I'm talking about. :) I'm not looking to migrate databases from one server to another. I'm talking of migrations in Rails Migrations sense. I added a hyperlink to the Migrator.NET project in hopes that it clarifies it a bit for others.

Answer (score 2):

Source control is for taking a snapshot of your current code base.  Migration is for moving changing your database from one version to the next.  So that at some future point you can take an old database, apply migrations and work with the latest code base.

I've never seen the actual migrations tested.  I have seen the results tested, and they have caught/reminded me to run the latest migrations.

```
describe User do
  it { should have_column :name, :type => :string }
  it { should validate_presence_of :name}       
end
```

So someone changes the model.  Adds a test to reflect the model.  Adds the migration.  Then commits the source.
You grab the latest, run tests.  Tests fail because the database doesn't correspond.  You remember to run migrations, then rerun tests. Success.

Comment: This would work only for simple 1:1 models, our database has a different structure than the domain model classes. I see your example is in Ruby (is that rspec?) and this would work with ActiveRecord, but we're not using that. We're using NHibernate to map database tables to our domain model entities and they don't match 1:1.

Comment: Yes, it's rspec.
If that's the case, I would probably do what Rawheiser suggests, just exercising the models.  It's harder to do with .net, but if you have already set up a dev and test database it would be easier to do.  If your mappings aren't 1:1, then it might be useful to spend the time setting up a clean test database to run tests against.  I've still never heard of anyone testing the migrations, but just testing the results of those migrations.

Comment: I'll give you +1, because your answer is good for ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 2):

Treat migrations testing as part of your overall persistence testing strategy if using NHibernate, i.e. if you can create and save all of your entities without any errors, your database **and** your mappings should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You COULD do a comparison of database system objects, but you would need to have a target against which to compare - otherwise how would you know if passed or failed?

I think you may be better off creating a set of edge case CRUD operation test cases that exercise the entities or operations in the data layer.  If any of these fail, the database is not in sync with what is required.  i.e. if the insert of an field char(20) fails because it is only char(15) in the database. Then the db structure comparison can be done to see what if off.

You may be able to short circuit this by focusing only on the recently changed items, and assuming prior changes have been applied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for an answer to this as well. I think this should be tested in an integration environment rather than a unit test one: For unit tests (DAL) I drop the database and re-create it.

However, ideally I'd like to have an integration environment were my DB is replicated from production and DB migration scripts run both ways:
Upwards to ensure a smooth upgrade of production and Downwards to ensure rollbacks are possible.